# simulación en java (canvas en java)

Tags: java, canvas, java-awt

Me encuentro realizando una simulación de un virus de computadora en java y pues estoy utilizando la canvas de `awt`, y bueno que es lo que consiste el problema es pintar unos computadores los cuales van a cambiar de color, ahora para pintar utilizo `paint`, pero no se como cambiarles el color a medida que pasa el tiempo o sea repintar con los cambios que deseo.

Creo que mejor me explicare con el codigo

```
// aqui es donde pinto 
public void paint(Graphics g) {
  super.paint(g);

  for ( int x = 20; x <= 1150; x += 25)
    for ( int y = 20; y <= 800; y += 25 ) {
      miClaseQo.pintar(x,y, g)        
    }
  }
}
```

pero aquello que pinto en algun momento cambia de estado, entonces como lo actualizo?, como pinto de nuevo
con las nuevas caracteristicas?.
**Edición:**
Busque el método `update` pero no encuentro algo sobre el en cambio encontré el `repaint` pero aun no se como utilizarlo

Comment: ya intentaste con setColor?

Comment: Más bien sería con el método [update](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Canvas.html#update(java.awt.Graphics)), ¿No?

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios, pero no se donde utilizar `setColor` para que me actualice el estado y no conozco el método `update` podrías por favor pasarme el enlace de la documentación